# label size too small for string vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Quick question. I've been having trouble with some of my labels. It only shows a limited set of strings as I run my project.

Ex.

Instead of showing the text "0 oCelsius, and -600 Kelvin", it only shows "0 oCelsius" instead.

My question is, where can i find the property of the label where in it doesn't limit any of my output strings?

If such property doesn't exist, can you suggest something else?

*Note - label text was called using datasets, dataadaptors, etc...

Comment: WinForms?  Labels have an AutoSize property.

Comment: got it. but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @earlchestersiaotong: if you got your answer post it as a separate answer and accept it so that future readers may see this and get help from it. It would help in maintaining the essence of StackOverflow.

Comment: @KashishArora sure thing. im new here so hanks for the tip :)